# How do you refresh inner HTML every second?

Tags: javascript

I have just started to learn how to code javascript from my college courses and I am having some trouble on this part that seems like it should work for me.

```
var cookieAmount = 0;
var cookiePerSecond = 0;
var cookiePerClick = 1;

function firstTimeLoad(){
   refreshClickStats();
}

function cookieClick(){
   cookieAmount += cookiePerClick;
   refreshClickStats();
}

function refreshClickStats(){
   var stats = "<p>You have " + cookieAmount + " cookies.<br>You have " + cookiePerSecond + " cookies per second.</p>";
   document.getElementById('cookieStats').innerHTML = stats;
}

function cookiePerSecondFunction(){
   cookieAmount =+ cookiePerSecond;
   refreshClickStats();
}

window.setInterval(cookiePerSecondFunction(), 1000);
```

The problem is that the setInterval always works once and then gives me a "cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". But if I comment the refresh function from the cookiesPerSecondFunction it doesn't give me an error. So what am I doing wrong the the 1 second timer is only working once and giving me an error the rest of the time?

Thanks,

Mark Mueller

Comment: there are a few errors with your code that may be contributing to the issue... 
1) document.getElementById not document.getById
2) var cookiePerSecond = 0: last character should be semicolon var cookiePerSecond = 0; 
3) seInterval is expecting a function as the first parameter, so change cookiePerSecondFunction() to cookiePerSecondFunction

Comment: sorry I had the hand type it because it wouldn't let me copy and paste the code. I don't have those errors in my original code but I will reply with original and non formatted.

Comment: var cookieAmount = 0;
var cookiePerSecond = 1;
var cookiePerClick = 1;

function firstTimeLoad(){
 refreshClickStats();
}

function cookieClick(){
 cookieAmount += cookiePerClick;
 refreshClickStats();
}

function refreshClickStats(){
 var stats = "<p>You have " + cookieAmount + " cookies.<br>You have " + cookiePerSecond + " cookies per second.</p>"; 
 document.getElementById('cookieStats').innerHTML =  stats;
}

function cookiePerSecondFunction(){
 cookieAmount += cookiePerSecond;
 refreshClickStats();
}

window.setInterval(cookiePerSecondFunction(), 1000);

Comment: `window.setInterval(cookiePerSecondFunction(), 1000);` should be `window.setInterval(cookiePerSecondFunction, 1000);`. no need for `()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var cookieAmount = 0;
var cookiePerSecond = 0;
var cookiePerClick = 1;

function firstTimeLoad() {
  refreshClickStats();
}

function cookieClick() {
  cookieAmount += cookiePerClick;
  refreshClickStats();
}

function refreshClickStats() {
  var stats = "<p>You have " + cookieAmount + " cookies.<br>You have " + cookiePerSecond + " cookies per second.</p>";
  document.getElementById('cookieStats').innerHTML = stats;
}

function cookiePerSecondFunction() {
  cookieAmount = ++cookiePerSecond;
  refreshClickStats();
}

window.setInterval(cookiePerSecondFunction, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="cookieStats"></div>
```